# Как своим компонентом обернуть другой?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть функциональные компонент Cell. Внутри него компонент с текстом. Таких Cell компонентов несколько.

Так вот как мне его создать, чтобы в него можно было вкладывать другие компоненты? Хочу в компоненте Cell 1 раз задать класс, чтобы не надо было постоянно его прописывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Надо в описание свойств `Cell` добавить свойтсво `children`

```
type CellProps {
   children: ReactNode
}

const Cell = ({ children }:CellProps) => {}
```

ну и использовать `children` уже внутри компонента, как хочется.